# cheap anti-fog agent!

Tags: safety, equipment

What are some safe and widely available alternatives to specifically formulated anti-fog sprays/treatments? Specifically for use on glasses, goggles, and face shields.

Comment: If the humidity from breath reaches the goggles, it indicates that the mask is not fitted properly. The exhaled air is supposed to go through the fabric, filtering out some of the droplets and aerosol, not escape into the goggles. Otherwise, the mask is not providing any benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to COVID-19, we've widely deployed face shields at work. Initially, there were a lot of employee complaints over fogging, and at the time it was difficult to find a steady supply of commercial products. We ended up testing a number of different alternatives, and finally settled on baby shampoo as it was both effective and unlikely to cause eye irritation if it got mixed with sweat and dripped into the employees eyes.

Get a couple drops on the surface, then use a paper towel (or preferably a microfiber rag or lint-free paper) to wipe it over the entire surface being protected. Once dry, it works very well.

Comment: Baby shampoo works well to prevent fog on swim goggles too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [excellent review article](https://www.edcmag.com/best-anti-fog-sprays/), which seems unbiased:

To quote the summary of favorites:

> Among those who were able to fulfill their promise, causing them to earn the trust of many anti-fog spray users, are Optix 55, Just Add Water, Splaqua, Z Clear, SURF BUTTA, Cressi, Hendlex, iGK, Scott Sports, and Atlan.

My personal recommendation is the most expensive one, Optix 55, as it lasts for days, while many others require frequent re-applications, which can apparently be not particularly trivial.

DISCLAIMER: I have no affiliations with any product and limited personal use.

Comment: I bought some anti mist sprays to find out more about them. there is no information about the ingredients of the spays on the bottle. I want to know what is the main antifog substance inside them.